# Git confused because file has been replaced with folder of the same name

Tags: git

I downloaded and opened Apple's new Pages version 5 (the Mavericks one). I opened and edited a file I have under Git control. Apple updated the file to its new format. The new format seems to be a folder with a series of files inside of it, maybe something akin to an app bundle.

Now when I tried to commit the change with Git, I get this message:

```
error: unable to index file docs/mydoc.pages
fatal: updating files failed
```

I have no idea how to deal with this. How can I get Git to accept that the file has been replaced with a folder with the same name?

Comment: Have you tried removing the file from the index and then (re-)adding the folder?

Comment: @Jahnux73 i don't understand how that link helps me when a product, without notifying me, turns a file into a folder...

Comment: @knittl I'm a git beginner, could you please tell me the git commands for doing this?

Comment: `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename; git add directory_name`

Comment: @knittl thanks, that almost did it, but i had to use "git rm -r --cached filename" for git to remove. one confused situation!

Comment: If it was a file (not a directory) beforehand, then you should not need the `-r` (recursive) flag. …Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @knittl's answer worked:

```
git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch mydoc.pages; git add mydoc.pages
```